# do I need to use full text search for domain names and Ip address?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, data-modeling

I do have domain names and ip address of it. this is almost 200k so when I redesign a table do I need to enable FULL TEXT SEARCH functionality of MySQL??

I want search table with domain names and IP address as well. means I search by domain then it should show IP address and if I search with IP then it should show domain names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends a bit on your data structure. If you have separate columns with domain names and IP addresses, this is not useful: just search for strings (or partial strings, with LIKE). If you have a large body of text (in a single column/field) which also includes domain names and IP addresses, then FULL TEXT SEARCH may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to use full text search and you don't need to enable FULL TEXT SEARCH.